# bad credentials response in oauth2 getting access token

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, python-requests

I am trying to get accees token oauth2 from a server but the response keeps saying Bad credentials,

```
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    }
    url = "http://172.15.39.95:8080/oauth/token"
    params = {"grant_type": "password", "username": "xxxxx", "password": "xxxxxx"}
    client_auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
    x = requests.get(url, params=params, auth=client_auth, headers=headers)
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to use the Resource Owner Password Credentials grant. The request method should be POST, not GET (if I read your python code correctly). See the example in the [OAuth2 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-39).
I would expect the server to return "HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed" error.

You should probably remove the `grant_type: client_credentials` header - you have the `grant_type` specified as a parameter with the correct value of `password`.

It's hard to say what the "Bad credentials" means, since you are not using the POST request method. When you change it, you should get more specific response. If your basic authentication client id + client secret is not valid, you should get

```
 HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
 Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
 Cache-Control: no-store
 Pragma: no-cache

 {
   "error":"invalid_client"
 }
```

and if your `username` + `password` params are invalid, you should get

```
 HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
 Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
 Cache-Control: no-store
 Pragma: no-cache

 {
   "error":"invalid_grant"
 }
```

See the [OAuth2 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.2) for more error codes.